# c# select process in listview and sendMessage to it

Tags: c#, listview, process

So i made a list view of processes and now i want to make it that i have to select a process in it and then send a message to it (in my case notepad).

How can i assign the notepad Process declaration to the selected listview item?

Here is what i have for now:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;


namespace sendMessage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);



        public void DisplayProcesses() {
            try
            {
                Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

                foreach (Process proc in processList)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(proc.ProcessName);
                    item.SubItems.Add(proc.ProcessName);
                    item.Tag = proc;
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private static void DoSendMessage(string message)
        {
            Process notepad = new Process();
            notepad.ProcessName=

            if (notepad != null)
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, message);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("No process...");
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TextBox is empty");
            }
            else {
                DoSendMessage(textBox1.Text);
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayProcesses();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The input to notepad is standard input.  So you need to communicate with NotePad by using the Standard Output of the Process().

Comment: I want to have it like this so i can select it from the lsitview in case i have more than 1 notepad processes and i want to select a specific one

Comment: I don't get what your issue is. Instead of just pasting all your code, paste what's relevant. Is there a specific reason why using `Tag` as you already do doesn't work?

Comment: In DoSendMessage(), i want the Process notepad to be assigned to the selected item(process) in listview. It is said clearly in my question.

Comment: You need to have a separate process for each NotePad Application unless you plan on connecting (a connection being a stream class which is a pipe) and disconnecting each application.  For multiple connections I recommend putting your Process into a class so you can have multiple instances of the class (one for each connection).